# Получение всех HTTP заголовков страницы

Tags: php, http, curl, http-заголовки

Всем привет. Допустим, есть сайт site.ru. С помощью данного скрипта я могу получить лишь сам адрес страницы:

```
if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'http://site.ru');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
$out = curl_exec($curl);
echo $out;
curl_close($curl);
}
```

В браузере вижу следующее:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sun, 14 May 2017 09:54:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Location: http://site.ru/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Как получить все заголовки, получаемые в инструментах разработчика (<kbd>F12</kbd>-><kbd>Network</kbd>)? (Кто знает расширение для хрома Creative Tester - Live HTTP Headers(логотип круга салатового цвета)[image: введите сюда описание изображения] - результат нужен примерно такой же, вернее, нужны только ссылки)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, [`get_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-headers.php):

```
<?php
print_r(get_headers('http://site.ru'));
?>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58948/discussion-on-answer-by----http--).

Answer (score 2):

```
$raw_headers = '';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, '__write_header');
public function __write_header($curl, $bytes)
{
    $GLOBALS['raw_headers'] .= $bytes;
    return strlen($bytes);
}
```

> CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION
>   Callback-функция принимает два параметра. Первым параметром является дескриптор cURL, вторым параметром является строка с записываемыми заголовками. Заголовки должны быть записаны с помощью данной callback-функции. Должна возвратить количество записанных байт.

[описание взято отсюда](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php)